# Proving $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(n^k+1)}{(n+1)^k}\zeta(k+1)\right)=\psi(\frac{n}{n+1})-\psi(\frac{1}{n+1})=\pi\cot(\frac{\pi}{n+1})$

Tags: trigonometry, riemann-zeta, pi, digamma-function

I'm an amateur/hobbyist mathematician, and I found this interesting relationship about 6 years ago, but haven't ever quite understood it! I feel like this is related to how Digamma and Zeta are connected, but I haven't seen this directly expressed anywhere before. Could someone explain this relationship, or other ways of expressing it?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{ \left( n^{k} - 1 \right)}{ \left( n + 1 \right)^{k}} \zeta \left( k+1\right) \right) = \psi \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) - \psi \left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = \pi \cot \left( \frac{\pi}{n+1} \right)$$

Also expressed as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{n^k - 1}{ \left( n+1 \right)^{k}} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^{k+1}} \right) = \psi \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) - \psi \left( \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). The last equality follows from the reflection formula for $\psi$.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde I have updated it! :) I didn't realize there was native latex rendering that's neat!

Comment: @Tristen. Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z|<1$ the [Digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) has the Taylor series,
$$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\zeta(k+1)z^k=-\gamma-\psi(1-z)$$
as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Taylor_series), where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant).

So for the first equality,

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \left[ \frac{  n^{k} - 1 }{ \left( n + 1 \right)^{k}} \zeta \left( k+1\right) \right] &= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^k\zeta(k+1)\right]-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}\zeta(k+1)\right] \\
&=-\gamma-\psi\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\left(-\gamma-\psi\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right) \\
&=\psi\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
\end{align*}$$
and the second equality is a direct result of the [Reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula) for the Digamma function.
$$\begin{align*}
\psi\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)&=\psi\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) \\
&=\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)
\end{align*}$$

---

For completeness, I will also show the Reflection formula.

Recall that for $z\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$\psi(z+1)=\psi(z)+\frac{1}{z}$$
this comes from taking the derivative of the relation $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$, then using $\psi(z)=\Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$. So we have,
$$\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=\psi(-z)-\psi(z)-\frac{1}{z}$$
whence by the [series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_representation) of the Digamma function we obtain,
$$\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N_0}}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k-z}\right)+\gamma-\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N_0}}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+z}\right)-\frac{1}{z}$$
which reduces to our desired expression.
$$\begin{align*}
\psi(1-z)-\psi(z)&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N_0}}\left(\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}\right)-\frac{1}{z} \\
&=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{2z}{z^2-k^2}\right)+\frac{1}{z} \\
&=\pi\cot(\pi z)
\end{align*}$$
The last equality comes from [$(4.22.3)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.22#E3) (Mittag-Leffler Cotangent), with $z=\pi z$ and multiplied by a factor of $\pi$.